# Selenium: Close button doesn't throw error but popup still doesn't close

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a Selenium test with a create-new-folder pop-up dialogue box which I want to close.
  I used a regular click to the Close-button of the dialogue box and it worked fine for a while.
Then, yesterday, it stopped working and now the box doesn't get closed anylonger.

At first I thought the button was not visible or not clickable or something like that, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.
I checked for all of that. So, the actual click action goes through without error, but the click still doesn't seem to work as the dialogue box remains open afterwards.

This is the code I currently use:

```
WebElement button = Utils.DRIVER.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='lotusFormButton' and @value='Cancel' and not(@disabled)]"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
new Actions(Utils.DRIVER).moveToElement(button).click().perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("dijitDialogUnderlay")));
```

I have no idea what I did wrong, I tried normal click.

`button.click();`

I have also tried `javascript` click

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) Utils.DRIVER;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

but none of it worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

The error message I get is the following:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to no longer be visible: By.className: dijitDialogUnderlay
```

The actual condition of the button being clickable is passed, but the timeout for the underlay of the dialogue box to vanish times out as the dialogue box isn't closed.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, despite me actually having tested whether the button was clickable or not beforehand it still seems to have been a race condition problem. With a simple `Thread.sleep(10000)` before the actual clicking of the button it runs through without problem.

That doesn't exactly answer why `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button)` says that the button is clickable when it actually isn't, but at least I now know that the actual clicking of the button wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try:

new Actions(Utils.DRIVER).moveToElement(button,10,10).doubleClick().perform();

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. What exactly does `element` refer to in your solution, as the button is already referenced in `moveToElement()` ?

Comment: remove 'element' .

Comment: try submit () method on button. And please post  dom xml.

Comment: Check is button inside a frame?  Is button clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the log details of the test failure.
And if you are working with pop ups, then you should not be using click. You have to use the SwitvhTo() property. 
For example,

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();//For accept
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();//For close
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It isn't an alert, it is a dialogue box that pops up. So I can't use dismiss() here.